Is there any way to save an inbred human population that also happens to be the last one left?
The world was destroyed temporarily, and almost everyone died. A few thousand people are all that's left of the human race, at least in that continent. Naturally, they did form a community and the community did grow, but their genetic diversity is plummeting and there are no outsiders to bring in that may add some new blood.
Is there any scientific way to save this population? Or is this problem beyond known science and can only be solved by supernatural means?

The genetic diversity is plummeting because most mutations are somehow blocked or else, most mutants are somehow barred from producing viable offspring; not directly because the members of the species are few. Why is that? Find the cause and fix it, diversity will soar again.

How advanced are your humans? Genetic editing is possible but were just scratching the surface right now with CRISPR

Iceland uses dating app that works off genealogy - because their population is so small that for natives it became a problem, so they solved it with least effort - working off family tree history, app notifies users they're meeting members of their family. two or three generations of such strict control should provide sufficient gene pool for inbreeding to not be much of a problem. Of course, individuals should keep watching out for potential familial mates, for purely health-related reasons, but it definitely is not a problem after couple of generations.

Generally, the answer is "abandon the nuclear family and aim for most recombination of genetic material in the shortest time."

@SimonRichter what family structure would be better?

@Thales, "tribe" hovering around Dunbar's number -- you want large groups for diversity, but still small enough that their social structures can be self-organizing, without a formal structure. With populations this small, resource allocation is also usually very informal, so everyone works for the benefit of the tribe, and there is no question of "supporting someone else's children", because mutual aid is the only social safety net there is.

How long was the population small?  Genetic drift would severely impact diversity it were not carefully shepherded if the fallen civilization were forced to stay small for long enough.

@SimonRichter that doesn't quite answer my question. You said they need to abandon the nuclear family. In favor of what?

We can't totally abandon the nuclear family. Human nature shows that pair bonding is very important for social stability. (See harm statistics on stepchildren.) But we can affirm every child born to a mother in the group is accepted. Group size can be as small as 5 or larger. By the group taking responsibility for children, we reduce the problem of men harming children of other men. This is not a panacea as under stress, even a tribe will kill a lot of their own children.

As answers already stated yes they could survive, however what is needed to survive would be difficult.  The vorkosigan saga explores that idea with the planet of Barrayar.  Given the frequency of mutation the best option, baring advanced genetic screenings and manipulations, is sadly infanticide.  If a newborn has any sign of genetic defects they are not raised.  This helps to limit the spread of deleterious mutations some, but more importantly the parents just don't have the resources to care for many children with health issues due to inbreeding.  survival won't be fun.

Few thousand people would be enough to replenish the Humanity, it has already happened.
The estimated minimal sample of an indefinitely survivable minimal sample is estimated to about 50-100 humans. Note that the current Amish population (more than 2million people) roots in only 2-300 original founders, they have various genetical defects, but far not enough to threat their survival. (They actually refuse genetical testing saying it is Gods will. And it looks, God is grateful to them for this level of belief, at least on the population genetical level).
However, your population has the option to not refuse genetical testing; instead they could use advanced genetical sequencing to identify the problematic genes. On this way they could form families lesser threatened by genetical defects. That would help to decrease the required minimal size of your initial population, again no one knows how much.
Probably there is no way to re-create the humanity from a single family without controlled DNA alternation or by supernatural means.
Playing with such things means that babies born with terrible defects and small children die in incurable, unspeakable suffering. It also means many people with mental disabilities not even knowing why do they suffer in their entire life. Basic moral and ethics dictates to not play with that without a rational reason (I think it is okay if there is only 100 place in the spaceship saving the Humanity, but it is not okay if you are just experimenting).

Will genetic diversity be replenished in time?

With continued survival? Yes, inevitably.
That's what mutations are.

@Thales Yes, also ours has replenished. Afaik races are only some 20-40000 years old.

@Thales Extending Abestranges comment: yes, all our genes have a natural mutation rate. Most of the mutations are never noticed. Most of the rest causes death in the early foetal age. The mutations with a visible change are exception in the exception. Mutations with an advantage are exception in the exceptions in the exceptions. But, the mutation rate can actually help to determine, when did populations branched away, for example (here helps that some genes are coming only from the mother or only from the father DNA, even these differ a little).

@Thales as already said with continued survival and enough time genetic diversity can be developed.  However when we talk about enough time were talking tens of thousands of years.  Unless your humans also lost all technology and ended up in the stone age likely their tech advancement would be such that they could cure health issues with direct genetic modification long before natural mutation lead to healthy genetic diversity.

Assuming a reasonably healthy DNA to start from any species can be brought back from near extinction with a single breeding par.
This is an old question that's been studied extensively.  With each study the number of humans necessary for bringing the population back keeps getting smaller.  With the number of people numbering in the thousands then nothing all that out of the ordinary would be required, just keep good records so close relatives don't end up as bearing children.
I remember seeing a sci-fi show that had the human population down to only 12 people and thought that there might be some significance to this number.  With a bit of searching the internet I found some study that claimed with careful selection of breeding pairs the human population could be brought back without much concern of inbreeding with only 6 breeding pairs.  I believe this study, and the sci-fi episode based off the premise, dates back to the 1990s.
There was a YouTube video that I saw which said that even with just one breeding pair the human population could be brought back but it would take a lot of work.  The first breeding pair would have to have as many children as possible.  Then their children would have to have as many children as possible.  Then just keep going until the population is large enough that things could return to the monogamous pairing and small family sizes most cultures today will practice.
Solving this with having as many children as possible does mean that there will be some people with severe congenital conditions from inbreeding, but unless there's some means to examine the DNA for detrimental conditions then select gametes by the DNA they contain then it comes down to taking a shotgun approach where it's just hitting the target by volume of fire.
As a real world example of a healthy population emerging from a small initial population consider the hippos in Colombia.  That population started with one male and three females and has now reached to hundreds of hippos.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopotamuses_in_Colombia
If you have a population of several thousand people to start with then perhaps nothing special needs to be done for a healthy human population long term.  If some detrimental effects from inbreeding had set in before this population was brought down to only a few thousand then perhaps some extra care would have to be taken.
In any case the more children a woman bears the better chances of long term survival of the species.  That is until the population reaches a size that this continent can support, but that's a different issue than inbreeding.

The "Noah's Ark" story would be genetic material from one man and four unrelated women (Noah+wife, his three sons don't count since they genetically derive from the first two, and then add the three daughters-in-law)

Can you link us to this study you mention?

I don't have a link to any study, it's mostly bits of trivia I picked up from soaking up a lot of science fiction and science fact.  There has been many studies on this done over time so finding the same study I saw years ago would be impossible since I don't recall enough to pick out which would be which.  The solution to the problem remains unchanged regardless, keep close relatives from having children so "bad" genes don't pile up on the offspring.  Losing genetic diversity isn't necessarily bad since that diversity includes a lot of diseases that would be incurable.

You can do prenatal testing of fetuses.
It's fairly easy to screen new fetuses for potential abnormalities. You can just have lots of pregnancies, abort the ones which have bad gene combinations, and then slowly eliminate bad recessive inbred alleles.

Incest produces lots of what are called heterozygous carriers. There's a 25% chance that two people with similar genes will have a bad gene combination, aa, which causes health issues. There's a 25% chance they'll eliminate the bad gene.
What you would do is test everyone for bad recessive alleles, and then avoid matching heterozygous carriers with heterozygous carriers as much as possible. Ideally they sleep with people who are homozygous dominant, with two good genes. You ban homozygous recessive carriers from breeding generally.
Over time, your genetics will improve.

I'm sorry, pundet squares are too simple for most real world genetics.  They can be used for a single deleterious gene sure, but if you have an entirely inbreed population then your looking at dozens and dozens of deleterious genes all floating around.  You're likely to end up in a case where any potential mate shares at least some deleterious genes with you no matter what you do.  Yes genetic screening could help, you could choose to favor less dangerous mutations over more dangerous ones when picking mates, but it's not a magic fix to all deleterious genes.

I don't know how inbred they are. It's 1000s of random people. They might have started genetically diverse and slowly crossbred. If so, it may be possible to limit the dangerous genes.
